# Find file size limit for a logical drive

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to find maximal file size for a logical drive? I.e. having drive letter (for example "C:") get maximal file size for underlying file system (for example 4Gb for FAT32).

Or if there is no standard way to do it, what's the best way to find file system of the drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this will help [GetVolumeInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx)

See also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364407(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: As far as I can see there is only max file name size, not max file size in GetVolumeInformation

Comment: Yes, but you are able to know name of the file system and you are able to use this information. Maximal file size is constant for file system.